# Algorithm for calculating the most cost-effective chemical mix

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**The problem**

I have four different chemicals and I know the fraction of the following compounds in each of them as follows:

```
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| Name             | ZrO2    | Al2O3   | SiO2    | Na2O    |  Price  |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| AZS              | 30%     | 50%     | 13%     | 1.8%    | 328.95  |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| Fine salt        | 25%     | 30%     | 43%     | 0.2%    | 203.95  |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| ZDCF             | 63%     | 1%      | 33%     | 0.4%    | 789.47  |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| AB fines         | 0%      | 95%     | 1%      | 4%      | 263.16  |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| HJO              | 90%     | 1%      | 1%      | 0.2%    | 1315.79 |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
```

I need to mix them together in order to get a mixture with the given target content (represented as a range):

```
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|
| Compound         | Min     | Target  | Max     |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|
| Zr02             | 32%     | 33%     | 34%     |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|
| Al203            | 49%     | 50%     | 52%     |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|
| Si03             | 15%     | 16%     | 17%     |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|
| Na20             | 1.3%    | 1.6%    | 2%      |
|------------------|---------|---------|---------|
```

- I need to find the cheapest combination of the chemicals that will give me a mixture with all values within the ranges.
- I am not compelled to use all chemicals in the mixture, if the target mixture can be attained without using the more expensive ones.

Here is a link to code sandbox with the values in above values defined in typescript: https://codesandbox.io/s/cost-effective-mix-imvz5?file=/src/index.ts:2162-2169

I understand that there is not a single solution, rather I need generate a result set with all possible combinations, filter out the combinations that do not have the target mixture and finally sort the remaining mixtures by price. I am just not sure how to express this programatically.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have an example of a mixture with part data and sum?

Comment: Second table represents an example of what is needed i.e. all four compounds in the mixture need to be within the ranges presented in the second table.

Comment: Isn't there information missing? If I take one count of AZS and one count of Fine Salt, how can I know the percentage of ZrO2 of the two together? In other words, what do the percentages indicate? (percentage of volume, of weight, of molecule count?) If volume, shouldn't we need to know the ratio between the volumes of AZS and Fine Salt? If weight, ... same thing with ratio of weight? If molecule count, ... same thing?

Comment: The percentages indicate content in weight per metric ton e.g. AZS contains 300 kg of Zr02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem, which appears to fall in the realm of Linear Programming (LP).  Using [jsLPSolver](https://github.com/JWally/jsLPSolver), and configuring the `model` variable with the data provided in the question, we arrive at the following code...

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/javascript-lp-solver/prod/solver.js"></script>

<script>
var model = {
    "optimize": "cost",
    "opType": "min",
    "constraints": {
        "Zr02": {"min": 0.32, "max": 0.34},
        "Al203": {"min": 0.49, "max": 0.52},
        "Si02": {"min": 0.15, "max": 0.17},
        "Na20": {"min": 0.013, "max": 0.02}
    },
    "variables": {
        "AZS": {
            "Zr02": 0.30,
            "Al203": 0.50,
            "Si02": 0.13,
            "Na20": 0.018,
            "cost": 328.95
        },
        "Fine Salt": {
            "Zr02": 0.25,
            "Al203": 0.30,
            "Si02": 0.43,
            "Na20": 0.002,
            "cost": 203.95
        },
        "ZDCF": {
            "Zr02": 0.63,
            "Al203": 0.01,
            "Si02": 0.33,
            "Na20": 0.004,
            "cost": 789.47
        },
        "AB Fines": {
            "Zr02": 0.00,
            "Al203": 0.95,
            "Si02": 0.01,
            "Na20": 0.04,
            "cost": 263.16
        },
        "HJO": {
            "Zr02": 0.90,
            "Al203": 0.01,
            "Si02": 0.01,
            "Na20": 0.002,
            "cost": 1315.79
        }
    },
};

var results = solver.Solve( model );
console.log( results );

let constraintResults = {};
for ( let v in results ) {
  if ( !( v === 'bounded' || v === 'feasible' || v === 'result' ) ) {
    for ( let c in model.constraints ) {
      constraintResults[ c ] = ( constraintResults[ c ] || 0.0 ) + model.variables[ v ][ c ] * results[ v ];
    }
  }
}
console.log( constraintResults );

</script>
```

Not knowing the ultimate purpose of your question, I feel compelled to indicate...

*DISCLAIMER:  You must independently verify and confirm the results of this method for determining least cost.  I shall not be liable for any indirect, incidental, special, consequential, or punitive damages, or any loss of profits or revenues, whether incurred directly or indirectly, or other intangible losses, resulting from your use of this program.*

Note that MS Excel has various solver algorithms available, and it's probably worthwhile to exercise the same constraints and variables in MS Excel to cross validate the use of the jsLPSolver...

Comment: Love the disclaimer, thanks. This seems like the reasonable thing to go for.

Comment: I threw the disclaimer in there as, although `jsLPSolver` is open source and appears to have a reasonable following plus a fair amount of forks that increases the level of confidence, I am not sure how many folks who use it actually understand the underlying algorithms.  Plus, the solution might be spitting out a local minimum rather than a global minimum, although your LP problem is fairly continuous so safe to say it's a global minimum.  Wrt the Excel Solver, a good resource for its use is https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/22/how-to-use-solver-in-excel-with-examples/ .