# What is the best way to build a solver algorithm in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, solver

I am building a financial application in which I have to solve for a rate( bond yield ) that discounts cashflows back to a present value. We are solving for the rate.

What would the best way to do this in Javascript? What I have works, but I feel it can be optimised as it currently might take 60/70ms even with a solid 'best guess' parameter.

Also - is there a algorithmic way of determining the iteratingIncrement and allowable error such that there is never a time when the iteratingIncrement is too large to be able to find the allowableError?

All suggestions very welcome.

Many Thanks

```js
const solveDcfYield = ( workoutCashflows, target, bestGuess=0.00, iteratingIncrement=0.000001, allowableError=0.0001, maxIterations=1000000) => {
    /**
     * @param               {array}             workoutCashflows                Array of cashflows for specific settle and exchange.
     * @param               {float}             target                          Value for which to solve toward.
     * @param               {float}             bestGuess                       Best Guess to optimise algorithm solve time. As percentage e.g. 5.00.
     * @param               {float}             iteratingIncrement              Value to increment solver each iteration.
     * @param               {float}             allowableError                  Minimum distance from target to solve, unless max iterations hit.
     * @param               {int}               maxIterations                   Maximum number of iterations to un in the solver
     * 
     * @return              {float}             r                               Rate/yield that discounts cashflows coto within allowableError of target
     */
    let iteratingDifference = allowableError + 10;
    let r = bestGuess/100;
    let iterations = 0;

    let startTime = new Date().getTime();

    while ((( iteratingDifference > allowableError) || (iteratingDifference < -allowableError)) && (iterations <= maxIterations)) {
        iteratingDifference = target - sumAndDiscountCashFlows(workoutCashflows, r);
        r = (iteratingDifference > 0) ? (r - iteratingIncrement) : (r + iteratingIncrement);
        iteratingDifference = parseFloat(iteratingDifference.toFixed(8));
        iterations = iterations + 1;
        if (iterations === (maxIterations - 1)){
            console.log("maximum iterations hit...");
        }
    };

    let endTime = new Date().getTime();
    let time = endTime - startTime
    console.log("Solver Algorithm Execution Time: ", time);

    return r;

};
```

Comment: Bonds pay the face value on the maturity date and coupon payments every six months that equal a specified percentage of the bond's face value, but you refer to "cashflows". By that do you mean the coupon payments and payment of the face value, or is the financial instrument in fact not a bond?

Comment: The best way to build a solver algorithm in Javascript is not to.  ; -)  You might want to consider employing an existing linear programming solver, such as https://github.com/JWally/jsLPSolver.  Although such a tool might not be more performant than your current custom algorithm, it will add a very flexible tool to a financial application.  A tool which presumably will find further use beyond just your current question...

Comment: @CarySwoveland These are coupon paying bonds so the cashflow are the coupons and the repayment of principle at maturity. Yes.

Comment: @Trentium thanks very much for the answer there. It seems strange that there is nothing prebuilt. Although most people must do most of these things serverside with python? Seems strange because python is so slow in comparison.

Comment: James, are there always two coupons paid per year? Presumably you are given the purchase price of the bond, its face value, the percentage coupon rate and maturity date, and wish to calculate the yield to maturity (i.e., the annual discount rate that causes the sum of PV's of coupon payments and the payment of the face value on the maturity date, to equal the purchase price of the bond).

Comment: @Trentium, how do you propose to formulate the linear program?

Comment: @CarySwoveland not always two coupons per year can be quarterly, semi-annual, monthly or annual. The purchase price is equal to the target in this case. Yes you are correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "The purchase price is equal to the *target*...". How are you defining "target"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655459/algorithm-for-calculating-the-most-cost-effective-chemical-mix/63662808#63662808 for an example of configuring a LP solver.  In short, the setup involves defining the variables and their constraints, in addition to the optimization objective.  Most LPs make use of stochastic gradient descent techniques (which are similar in nature to the Newtonian method in your answer) although applied concurrently across the entire range of variables.  (Consequently, one must also be weary of local versus global optimizations...)

Comment: @Trentium, I am familiar with [LP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Basis_exchange_algorithms) modelling and solution techniques. I was asking how you propose to formulate the OP's problem as a linear program. Incidentally the two classes of solution techniques for LPs are the simplex method and so-called *interior point methods*, both of which are guaranteed to produce an optimal solution if one exists. I'm not familiar with "stochastic gradient descent techniques". Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @CarySwoveland to tell you the truth, I'm not quite sure yet how to formulate Jame's question as an LP, but it has the aroma of an LP given the iterative search governed by a target goal.  Your excellent answer also suggests a similar path with Newton's method...  As I understand the question, the algorithm presented is functioning, but not performant.  Without seeing the entire functioning algorithm (ie, `sumAndDiscountCashFlows` is not defined and an example or two would help) I hesitate to roll up my sleeves...

Comment: @CarySwoveland ...oh, and stochastic gradient descent is actually a method out of the field of AI to converge neural nets, which leverage gradient descent optimizers to accelerate convergence.  Optimizers that might come in handy as a reference model to employ here, but admittedly, this might be overreach on my part...

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way to compute the yield to maturity of a bond<sup>1</sup> is to use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), which requires the calculation of derivatives, which I derive below.

---

You can express your problem as follows.

- n = number of years until maturity
- f = value of bond after n years (face value)
- c = annual coupon payment (percentage of f)
- p = purchase cost of bond
- i = annual yield to be determined

Let

```
α = 1/(1+i)
```

Then

p = α<sup>n</sup>f + c(1+α<sup>-0.5</sup>)Σ<sub>j=1.. n</sub>α<sup>j</sup>

Note that α<sup>-0.5</sup> is an adjustment that slightly increases the value of mid-year coupons so that they may be discounted from the end of the same year to provide an equivalent present value. This follows from the following identity.

α(cα<sup>-0.5</sup>) = cα<sup>0.5</sup>

As

Σ<sub>j=1.. n</sub>α<sup>j</sup>

is seen to be the sum of a geometric series we can write:

p = fα<sup>n</sup> + (1+α<sup>-0.5</sup>)cα(α<sup>n</sup>-1)/(1-α)

which is equivalent to the following:

p = (f(1-α) + (1+α<sup>-0.5</sup>)αc)α<sup>n</sup> - (1+α<sup>-0.5</sup>)αc)(1-α)<sup>-1</sup>

---

Now define the following functions.

g1(α) = (1+α<sup>-0.5</sup>)ac

g2(α) = (f(1-α)+g1(α))

g3(α) = α<sup>n</sup>

g4(α) = (1-α)<sup>-1</sup>

g5(α) = g2(α)g3(α)-1

h(α) = g1(α)g5(α)g4(α)

We wish to find α<sup>+</sup> for which

h(α<sup>+</sup>) = p

As α<sup>+</sup> = 1/(1+i), the yield to maturity therefore equals 1/α<sup>+</sup>-1.

---

The derivative of `h` relative to `α` is as follows:

h'(α) = g1'(α)g5(α)g4(α) + g1(α)g5'(α)g4(α) + g1(α)g5(α)g4'(α)

where

g1'(α) = (-0.5α<sup>-1.5</sup>)ac + (1+α<sup>-0.5</sup>)c

g2'(α) = -f+g1'(α)

g3'(α) = nα<sup>n-1</sup>

g4'(α) = -1/(1-α)<sup>2</sup>

g5'(α) = g2'(α)g3(α) + g2(α)g3'(α)

---

We might begin by setting α equal to some average yield α<sub>0</sub>. Then estimate a new value of α using the straight-line approximation (i.e., Newton's method):

h(α<sub>0</sub>) + (α<sub>0</sub>+d)*h'(α<sub>0</sub>) = p

and solving for d:

d = (p-h(α<sub>0</sub>))/h'(α<sub>0</sub>) - α<sub>0</sub>

The new estimate of α is therefore α + d. Next, calculate

d = (p-h(α))/h'(α) - α

update α and continue in this fashion until the change in α is sufficiently small. This should quickly converge, certainly faster that methods that do not use derivates.

<sup>1. A bond's yield to maturity is the annual discount rate that causes the purchase price of the bond to equal the sum of the present values of coupon payments (two per year) plus the present value of the payment of the bond's face value on the maturity date.</sup>

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland how could we adjust this to be able to accomodate for varying coupon cashflow amounts? In order to be able to accomodate floating rate notes (where every coupon will be different) I must pass in the cashflows as an array instead of using an annual cashflow/coupon rate. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: James. I asked you about that yesterday. You seemed to agree with my statement of the problem. Nevertheless, I asked for greater specificity. When after about 16 hours you had not replied I prepared an answer based on two coupons paid per year, which I understand is common for bonds. If the coupon rate and number of coupons per year are fixed, my answer can be modified easily. If, for example, there were four coupons per year only the term (1+α^-0.5) need be be changed, to 1+α^-0.25+α^-0.5+α^-0.75. If, however,...

Comment: ...coupon rates can change by year (which I have not heard of for bonds), the problem becomes extremely messy, a problem that I have neither the time nor interest in pursuing.

Comment: Thanks nonetheless @Caryswoveland. Coupons on floating rate bonds pay a fixed rate above the benchmark (similar to fed interest rate). So in order to accurately calculate the yield we must use the market-implied forecast of the interest rate when the cashflow will be paid. Thus every coupon will differ. Your solution is novel and I enjoyed it, I'm not great on SO etiquette so please let me know how I can give the appropriate kudos.